# AudioConstraints don't work with navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia

Tags: javascript, getusermedia, mediastream, mediadevices

No matter what I set for the audio constraints, it doesn't seem to affect the audio stream's settings. I have tried different microphones and browsers. I'm trying to get the highest quality stream. I would like a 192k bitrate but I'm not quite sure how sample rate and sample size translate to bitrate.

```
var textarea = document.createElement('pre');
document.body.insertBefore(textarea,document.body.firstChild)

var constraints =  {
  audio: { 
            sampleSize: 24 //no number works
            sampleRate: 41000 //nothing works unless I use a bad number like 8, then it drops to 24000
         }
}
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then(function success(stream) {
    stream.getTracks().forEach(function(track) {
    textarea.innerHTML = textarea.innerHTML+track.kind+":"+JSON.stringify(track.getSettings(),null, 2);
    })
}).catch(function(err) {
   textarea.innerHTML = err.message;
});
```

codepen example: https://codepen.io/trackedsupport/pen/BamNvXZ

Comment: Some constraints are tied to the browser. Check  [Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getSupportedConstraints) as a start.

Comment: That page shows sampleSize and sampleRate as supported. But theres no way I can change it? Then why is it supported?

Comment: I just read that those 2 properties are [ConstrainULong](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaTrackConstraints#constrainulong) objects, not just numbers. Tell me if it helps.

Comment: Nope. Im guessing it just can't get anything different than 4800 and 16. I made a codepen to easily test. https://codepen.io/trackedsupport/pen/BamNvXZ

Comment: Nvm. Those are properties of `MediaTrackConstraints`. FYI, your code worked in my machine though (using Brave Browser).

Comment: I downloaded Brave but nothing worked there for me.